# What is gin_trgm_ops of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am using a query where the following line written

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON public.roads_r USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

Its returning the following error

> operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Have you searched for the answer yourself?  The very first hit from Google explained it to me.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good question for [gis.se] because it has nothing to do with PostGIS. This is a PostgreSQL question on Trigram indexing, and it's better suited for [dba.se]

Answer (score 14):

It's part of the PostgreSQL Trigram Index support and it's provided by the `pg_trgm` extension.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

This is normally packaged with PostgreSQL as a `-contrib` module. If this doesn't work for you check with your distro.

Answer (score 3):

When using pg_trgm for trigram text matching you need

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_grgm
```

As it is said [in the official docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgtrgm.html)

I faced the same problem creating GIN indexes, but it's another problem. You also need some other extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin
```

Although it is not related to this topic, [I found the solution here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37351/postgresql-exclude-using-error-data-type-integer-has-no-default-operator-class)

Comment: You do not need the btree_gin extension to create this index. The btree_gin extension will do nothing here.

Answer (score 1):

`gin_trgm_ops` is not a PostGIS feature. It's an available feature for the base database technology, PostgreSQL. It does have to be enabled by calling `CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm`, but it's a text search feature, not a spatial feature. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) for details. PostGIS only extends PostgreSQL with spatial types, functions, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Note that you also need to be connected to the database in which you want to create the pg_grgm extension.

e.g.

```
\c database_name
CREATE INDEX table_gin_trgm_idx ON table USING gin (col gin_trgm_ops);
```